# Galera cluster truncate table

Tags: mariadb, galera

I have a Galera cluster with three node and they are synced. when I truncate a table in master, the same table is not truncated in other nodes. Also when I truncate, it does not even go to syncing mode. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Is it a full table or a temp table? If temp, might be [MDEV-26028](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-26028), But otherwise looks odd, MariaDB test do cover this. Write a [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org) with version details.